# The batch_size meaning of the on-policy Reinforcement Learning in stable-baselines3?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I use stable-baselines3 to train a model of PPO, I am questionable for the param "batch-size"[image], does on-policy learning has the definition of the batch-size? My teacher taught me the PPO will be update itself when finished a episode, what's the meaning of the "batch-size" of the PPO in the stable-baselines3?